# NuGet пакет с статическими файлами (.NET core)

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, mvc, .net-core

В .NET Framework есть прекрасная возможность паковать статические файлы(html,css,js) в NuGet пакеты. А потом при его подключении в проект мы получали этот контент.

В .NET core тоже собирается пакет с статическими данными. НО, статические данные не интегрируются в новый проект как в .NET Framework. Интегрируются только dll файлы.

Паковал с помощью NuGet package explorer и Octo.exe.
Пробовал писать PowersShell скрипты в пакете. Но увы, в core они тоже не работают.
Кто что посоветует?

Comment: Вы про это: [Статические файлы](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/2.5.php) и [Работа статических файлов в ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files)?

Comment: Нет. В Ваших ссылках описана просто как ссылаться на статические файлы.
Меня интересует интегрирование любых статических файлов в NuGet пакет и извлечение данных из этого пакета в новый проект.

Comment: @VyacheslavShymkovych а вы можете привести пример как вы пытались делать?